# List all "People" albums in Google Photos API

Tags: javascript, api, google-photos, google-photos-api

I was wondering if there was any way to use `albums.list` or any other API which will return a list of all the faces you have in your Google Photos?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/photos/)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I did look at their API the closest thing I saw was the albums.list which does not return face albums.

Comment: If it’s not listed in their api then that data is likely not available.